# Room Database insert method problem

Tags: java, android

insert in ArticleDao cannot be applied
не понимаю что не так

cannot resolve method 'map()'

**.map(dbArticleList -> articleDao.insert(dbArticleList))**

```
Observable<List<DbArticle>> observable = apiClient.getArticleList("us", "sports")
                .map(articleList -> converter.convert(articleList)
                        .map(dbArticleList -> articleDao.insert(dbArticleList))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

```js
@Dao
public interface ArticleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM DbArticle ORDER BY id DESC")
    Flowable<List<DbArticle>> getDbArticle();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    List<Long> insert(List<DbArticle> dbArticleList);
```

```js
public class Converter {
    @Inject
    Converter() {
    }

    public List<DbArticle> convert(List<Article> articleList) {
        List<DbArticle> dbArticleList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Article article : articleList) {
            DbArticle dbArticle = new DbArticle();
            dbArticle.author = article.author;
            dbArticle.description = article.description;
            dbArticle.publishedAt = article.publishedAt;
            dbArticle.title = article.title;
            dbArticle.url = article.url;
            dbArticle.urlToImage = article.urlToImage;
            dbArticleList.add(dbArticle);
        }
        return dbArticleList;
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot resolve method 'map()' означает, что у объекта, с которым вы работаете, нет такого метода. converter.convert(articleList) вам возвращает List, дальше необходимо его перевести в stream, и потом вызывать map(). Вот так: converter.convert(articleList).stream().map()...

Comment: Спасибо, я просто создал переменную типа Observable<List<DbArticle>> и вызвал у нее .map()